# Extract Certain Data Rows From Excel File Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What im trying to do is to extract certain rows using a keyword from excel file using HTML + Javascript and auto fill the data in HTML form. Noted that my excel file consists of different sheet,

For example i want to extract data rows from user_id=1, so it'll retrieve all data related to row for user_id =1 and use that data to auto fill form at my HTML page.

I've no clue how to do this but im leaving a code where it managed to extract excel data to html table but it just doesnt work based on my requirements. Any thoughts?

```js
  function ExportToTable() {
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xlsx|.xls)$/;
            /*Checks whether the file is a valid excel file*/
            if (regex.test($("#excelfile").val().toLowerCase())) {
                var xlsxflag = false; /*Flag for checking whether excel is .xls format or .xlsx format*/
                if ($("#excelfile").val().toLowerCase().indexOf(".xlsx") > 0) {
                    xlsxflag = true;
                }
                /*Checks whether the browser supports HTML5*/
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var data = e.target.result;
                        /*Converts the excel data in to object*/
                        if (xlsxflag) {
                            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
                        }
                        else {
                            var workbook = XLS.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
                        }
                        /*Gets all the sheetnames of excel in to a variable*/
                        var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;

                        var cnt = 0; /*This is used for restricting the script to consider only first sheet of excel*/
                        sheet_name_list.forEach(function (y) { /*Iterate through all sheets*/
                            /*Convert the cell value to Json*/
                            if (xlsxflag) {
                                var exceljson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);
                            }
                            else {
                                var exceljson = XLS.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[y]);
                            }
                            if (exceljson.length > 0 && cnt == 0) {
                                BindTable(exceljson, '#exceltable');
                                cnt++;
                            }
                        });
                        $('#exceltable').show();
                    }
                    if (xlsxflag) {/*If excel file is .xlsx extension than creates a Array Buffer from excel*/
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer($("#excelfile")[0].files[0]);
                    }
                    else {
                        reader.readAsBinaryString($("#excelfile")[0].files[0]);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert("Sorry! Your browser does not support HTML5!");
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("Please upload a valid Excel file!");
            }
        }
        function BindTable(jsondata, tableid) {/*Function used to convert the JSON array to Html Table*/
            var columns = BindTableHeader(jsondata, tableid); /*Gets all the column headings of Excel*/
            for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
                var row$ = $('<tr/>');
                for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
                    var cellValue = jsondata[i][columns[colIndex]];
                    if (cellValue == null)
                        cellValue = "";
                    row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
                }
                $(tableid).append(row$);
            }
        }
        function BindTableHeader(jsondata, tableid) {/*Function used to get all column names from JSON and bind the html table header*/
            var columnSet = [];
            var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');
            for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
                var rowHash = jsondata[i];
                for (var key in rowHash) {
                    if (rowHash.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {/*Adding each unique column names to a variable array*/
                            columnSet.push(key);
                            headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $(tableid).append(headerTr$);
            return columnSet;
        }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.7/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xls/0.7.4-a/xls.core.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        table { margin-top: 20px; border-collapse: collapse; display: none; }
        table th, table td { border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px 10px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="file" id="excelfile" />
    <input type="button" id="viewfile" value="Export To Table" onclick="ExportToTable()" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <table id="exceltable">
    </table>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```